# Multiplication, different multiplier by level

Tags: r

I am stuck with this problem

I want to multiply my data but each proportion of each observation for a different percentage.
As example: if the first observation of my Var_1 has 5000 value.
I want to multiply the proportion between 100 and 1000 by 2% (in this particular case 900 x 2%).
The proportion between 1000 and 2000 by 3% (in this case 1000 x 3%).
And the proportion >2000 by 5% (in this case 3000 x 5%).

And add the sum of this process for each observation in a new variable.
Any idea of how to proceed?

I have these data like example:

`library(tidyverse)
my_data <- tibble(Var_1 = c(5000, 1500, 350, 1200, 750, 1000,1250, 2500))`

Comment: Can you please check my solution

Answer (score 0):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
my_data %>%
    mutate(prop = case_when(between(Var_1, 100, 1000) ~ Var_1 * 0.02, 
                            between(Var_1, 1000, 2000) ~ Var_1 * 0.03,
                            Var_1 > 2000 ~ Var_1 * 0.05))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to load a package just for this one operation. You can use the subset(...) function from base R. It may be tempting to write an ifelse statement and that would probably work, but R excels when you use vectorized operations rather than loops.

```
# 1000 randomly selected numbers between 0 and 3000
data <- sample(c(0:3000), 1000, replace = TRUE)

# Multiply the data by a percentage based on it's value.
# It is tempting to do this with ifelse statements but R
# is best at vectorised operations so use the subset(...) function

# Multiply values between 100 and 1000 by 0.02
data[subset(data, data >= 100 & data < 1000)] <- data[subset(data, data >= 100 & data < 1000)] * 0.02

# Multiply values between 1000 and 2000 by 0.03
data[subset(data, data >= 1000 & data < 2000)] <- data[subset(data, data >= 1000 & data < 2000)] * 0.03

# Multiply values greater than 2000 by 0.05
data[subset(data, data >= 2000)] <- data[subset(data, data >= 2000)] * 0.05
```

Comment: I think this way doesnt work. For example for my first observation 5000 the output should be: 900 * 2% + 1000 * 3% + 2000 * 5% = 148

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? Do you want to multiply subsets of 5000 by percentages and sum the total? I am not sure what your goal is.

Comment: Imagine I have this variable c(5000, 2500, 1200) 
I want to multiply each proportion of each number for a different percentage. 
The percentages are: 
2% for the part of the number between 100 and 1000. 
3% for the part of the number between 1000 and 2000.
4% for the part of the number greater than 2000. 
In this case for: 
a) 5000 
3000*4% + 1000*3% + 900*2% = 168
b) 2500
500*4% + 1000*3% + 900*2% = 68
b) 1200
0*4% + 200*3% + 900*2% = 24
And I am looking for a way to do it for a variable with 20.000 numbers

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more generic way:

```
# First create a table of intervals and multipliers
bins <- data.frame(from = c(0, 100, 1000, 2000),
                   to = c(100, 1000, 2000, Inf),
                   multiplier = c(0, 0.02, 0.03, 0.05))

# Join that table to *every* row of your starting data
df <- merge(bins, my_data, all=TRUE) %>% mutate(

  # Calculate the overlap between each interval and your value
  interval_length = pmax(pmin(df$Var_1, df$to) - from, 0),

  # Multiply the amount of overlap by the given percentage
  amount = interval_length * multiplier
)

# Add up all the calculated amounts
sum(df$amount)
```